# Play Framework and Threadpools

Tags: playframework, threadpool

Is there a limit on the number of threads that Play framework exposes to my application? Is the thread size inside Play app so darn precious? What if I use a thread pool that I create by myself in the application and not use the one provided by Play. Is this recommended? Can anyone please throw some light on how Play handles threads?

Comment: Any takers? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limit of threads in your Play application would have to basically be determined by the maximum memory allocated to the VM. Threads will consume a fair bit of memory each, since they get their own stack. Essentially, the maximum number of threads possible depends on the arguments you will pass to the JVM and the total RAM on your computer, etc.

You should let Play manage threads for you. The configuration documentation is located [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ThreadPools). Part of the design of Play deals in minimizing the number of threads you need, so unless you're doing a lot of blocking calls you shouldn't need to touch it.

Play uses Akka to handle the threading. The configuration for the internal actor system can be found [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L21-L22). The juicy part in this is the `parallelism-factor` and `parallelism-max`. If we look at the well commented [reference configuration](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L284-L293) for Akka:

```
# The parallelism factor is used to determine thread pool size using the
# following formula: ceil(available processors * factor). Resulting size
# is then bounded by the parallelism-min and parallelism-max values.
parallelism-factor = 3.0

# Max number of threads to cap factor-based parallelism number to
parallelism-max = 64
```

Play's `parallelism-factor` by *default* is set to 1, based on the reference configuration. This means that by default, Play will have a thread pool equal to the number of processors available, to a maximum of 24.

Comment: What happens if I use my own ExecutionContext for blocking operations and not use the one from Play? Is this a good approach?

Comment: Honestly it won't make much of a difference since either way you're using up threads. Only thing you should do, if you intend on doing blocking calls, is to increase Play's threadpool size using the configuration.

Comment: Have a look at monifu https://github.com/monifu/monifu/wiki/Schedulers This seems to use a different execution context that can create and spawn threads independant of the thread pool that I get from Play?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, but you should avoid doing so unless if its a library. Its only good convention, you can do what you want.

Comment: I think I might not understand your question.

Comment: My question was, if I create my own threads using the Execution Context that I supply, who is in control of those threads?What will happen if the threads that I spawn outlive my Play server (even after the server stopped)? Is this a good practice

Comment: Those are two questions :) Naturally, it will be you who will be in control of those threads. Whether it is good practice depends on what you're trying to do.